# Pycharm: ошибка "нет такого файла"

Tags: python, pycharm

В одной и той же директории хранятся 3 файла: 1.txt, 2.txt и 3.txt.

При выполнении кода пайчарм выдает такую ошибку:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '3.txt'

Кто-нибудь знает в чем дело? Почему именно 3.txt, а не 2.txt или 1.txt?

Comment: Приведите проблемный фрагмент кода. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Проблемный фрагмент кода: `    with open(catalog_path, 'r', encoding='cp1251') as read_file:
        file_lines = read_file.readlines()
        count = len(file_lines)
        files_data["files"] = file_lines`

Comment: То, что вы привели, не является минимальным **воспроизводимым** примером. Стоит указать откуда берется `catalog_path` и структуру файлов проекта или директории, откуда берутся файлы (используйте `dir /S project_folder` *для win* или `ls -R project_folder` *для linux*)